# How to avoid duplicate legend labels in plotly or pass custom legend labels

Tags: python, plotly

How can I avoid duplicate legend labels in subplots? One way I would go about it in matplotlib would be to pass custom legend labels to an legend object. I couldn't find any documentation for an equivalent option in plotly. Any ideas?

```
traces = []

colors = {'Iris-setosa': 'rgb(31, 119, 180)', 
          'Iris-versicolor': 'rgb(255, 127, 14)', 
          'Iris-virginica': 'rgb(44, 160, 44)'}

for col in range(4):
    for key in colors:
        traces.append(Histogram(x=X[y==key, col], 
                        opacity=0.75,
                        xaxis='x%s' %(col+1),
                        marker=Marker(color=colors[key]),
                        name=key
                        )
                     )

data = Data(traces)

layout = Layout(barmode='overlay',
                xaxis=XAxis(domain=[0, 0.25], title='sepal length (cm)'),
                xaxis2=XAxis(domain=[0.3, 0.5], title='sepal width (cm)'),
                xaxis3=XAxis(domain=[0.55, 0.75], title='petal length (cm)'),
                xaxis4=XAxis(domain=[0.8, 1], title='petal width (cm)'),
                yaxis=YAxis(title='count'),
                title='Distribution of the different Iris flower features')

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Plotly controls this on the trace level. Try passing in `showlegend=False` inside the `Histogram` traces that you don't want to appear in the legend.

Reference: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#Histogram-showlegend

Example: https://plot.ly/python/legend/#Hiding-Legend-Entries

Direct copy-paste from the link above.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
# Fill in with your personal username and API key
# or, use this public demo account
py.sign_in('Python-Demo-Account', 'gwt101uhh0')

trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[1, 2, 3],
    name='First Trace',
    showlegend=False
)
trace2 = Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3],
    y=[8, 4, 2, 0],
    name='Second Trace',
    showlegend=True
)
data = Data([trace1, trace2])
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='show-legend')
```

The usage you want to see is shown in `trace1` above.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka But if the legend for `trace1` is hidden, then you can't control or hide `trace1`'s traces.

Comment: If one need to generate plots in a loop, you can use a `set` to keep track of which trace name have been added to the Figure yet, then use `showlegend=True if tracename not in set_tracenames else False`

Comment: @JossieCalderon AmourK's answer handles this using `legendgroup`. There's a useful example here: https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend-items

Answer (score 15):

This is a code snippet I came up with which avoids to set `showlegend=False` manually on each trace with a duplicate `name`.

```
names = set()
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace:
        trace.update(showlegend=False)
        if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))
```

`fig.for_each_trace` calls the passed function for each trace. The function keeps track of which legend names already occurred (via the set `names`, like @LucG proposed in a comment), and hides legend entries for duplicate (or triplicate, ...) names.

The code needs to be run after all traces have been added to the figure, and before it is `show`n.

Comment: Great answer. @Chris P's answer does not work for plotly timeline, this anwer does. Thank  you A. Donda.

Answer (score 10):

**A better way:**

Set the `legendgroup` option to the legend label you want for each trace. 
This will allow you to filter everything in the same group.

Hide the remaining traces' legends using the `showlegend=False` option.

This will give the exact behaviour you want.

**Old Solution (Not recommended):**

There is a another solution by adding "dummy" traces and hiding the data but only showing the legend.
With this method you cannot slice any of the data (which is not a bad thing).

```
trace_dummy = Scatter(
    x=[0, 0, 0], # Data is irrelevant since it won't be shown
    y=[0, 0, 0],
    name='Whatever Trace',
    showlegend=True,
    visible="legendonly"
)
```

Comment: I don't understand how one would use `legendgroup` for this purpose. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Take a look at the grouped legend section of `https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend`

Comment: @A.Donda If u wanna filter out data belonging to a legend, using `showlegend=False` will only filter out part of the data, since the other part's legend is hidden. But if u use `legendgroup`, filtering out the part that is shown in the legend will also filter out the hidden one, since they are in the same legend group