# Avoiding duplicate legends with R plotly subplot results in missing points

Tags: plotly, r-plotly

**Updated with more complete example**

Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939121, I am producing a series of marker-type plots with R `plotly` 4.8 that are combined with plotly::subplot, and I'm hiding the legend in the first of each pair of the component plots so that the final plot does not have duplicated legends.  But when doing this, only the first (x,y) point is shown for each of the two data frames being plotted (the top two plots).  The test code that demonstrates this is below.

```
require(plotly)
set.seed(1)

a <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3)
b <- data.frame(x=(1:3)+.1, y=(1:3)+.1)
xu <- runif(1000, 0, 3)
xn <- (rnorm(1000) + 3) / 2
co <- 'black'
p <- plot_ly()
pa <- add_markers(p, mode='marker',
                  data=a, x=~x, y=~y, name='j', legendgroup='j',
                  size=I(5), color=I(co),
                  showlegend=FALSE)

pb <- add_markers(p, mode='marker',
                  data=b, x=~x, y=~y, name='j', legendgroup='j',
                  size=I(5), color=I(co),
                  showlegend=TRUE)

pc <- add_histogram(p, x=~xu, name='k', color=I('black'),
                    legendgroup='k', showlegend=FALSE)
pd <- add_histogram(p, x=~xn, name='k', color=I('black'),
                    legendgroup='k', showlegend=TRUE)

plotly::subplot(pa, pb, pc, pd, shareX=TRUE, shareY=FALSE, titleX=TRUE, nrows=4)
```

Thanks for any pointers.  To have points suppressed from the output of `add_markers` I must have some basic misunderstanding of `plotly`.

Here's the output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2.2 plotly_4.8.0   ggplot2_3.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 pillar_1.3.0       compiler_3.5.1     later_0.7.3        plyr_1.8.4        
 [7] bindr_0.1.1        tools_3.5.1        digest_0.6.15      jsonlite_1.5       tibble_1.4.2       gtable_0.2.0      
[13] viridisLite_0.3.0  pkgconfig_2.0.2    rlang_0.2.2        shiny_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.7     crosstalk_1.0.0   
[19] yaml_2.2.0         withr_2.1.2        dplyr_0.7.6        httr_1.3.1         htmlwidgets_1.2    grid_3.5.1        
[25] tidyselect_0.2.4   glue_1.3.0         data.table_1.11.4  R6_2.2.2           purrr_0.2.5        tidyr_0.8.1       
[31] magrittr_1.5       scales_1.0.0       promises_1.0.1     htmltools_0.3.6    assertthat_0.2.0   xtable_1.8-2      
[37] mime_0.5           colorspace_1.3-2   httpuv_1.4.5       lazyeval_0.2.1     munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: in `pa`, if I replace `color=I('black')` with `color=~y` it works. In order to get a legend you need to attribute a color or a size.

Comment: I'm not clear on that.  I don't want a separate color for each value of y, and I'mm going to be adding lines and other traces and I want to be able to click some of the traces off  by clicking on their part of the legend.

Comment: That's a link back to this same page - did you mean to give a link to a different page?

Comment: sorry, have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948151/in-r-plotly-subplot-graph-how-to-show-only-one-legend

Comment: Thanks.  The main point I got from that was to switch the order of `showlegend=TRUE` and `FALSE`.  I tried that but still no legend and only one point shown per plot.  I tried removing `size=I(5), color=I('black')` and all the points showed, but the two plots used different color points and the legend still did not appear.

Comment: The legends are appearing correctly now but for each of the `add_markers` plots only first first of each triplet of points is drawn.  I've expanded the example in the original post.  I must be missing something basic about `plotly`.

Comment: When I run your new code, I have 3 points in each of the top two graphics.

Comment: I must be doing something odd.  I run at the command line which gives an auto-preview in Google Chrome and I see only the one point in each part.  Are you knitting to html?  How are you rendering the graphic?

Comment: in R studio. Maybe add your `sessionInfo()` to your post.

Comment: Adding sessionInfo now.  I ran this as an ordinary R script in RStudio and only saw one point per panel.  I did not run this as a markdown document or using knit to html.  I'm just looking at the Viewer in RStudio.

Comment: I am using `plotly_4.7.1.9000  ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`.

Comment: This remains mysterious, but I have developed a more comprehensive function using a data frame to drive a set of `plotly` graphics combined with `subplot`, and everything is working as it should as long as I don't use `add_trace` but instead use `add_markers` and `add_lines`.  I do sort the data frame in this new example, which perhaps has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? I think the issue was in the way you had specified `size`. The attribute `marker` controls the size of the points.

```
require(plotly)
set.seed(1)

a <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3)
b <- data.frame(x=(1:3)+.1, y=(1:3)+.1)
xu <- runif(1000, 0, 3)
xn <- (rnorm(1000) + 3) / 2
co <- 'black'
p <- plot_ly()
# attribute 'marker' controls size of points
pa <- add_markers(p, 
                  data=a, x=~x, y=~y, name='j', legendgroup='j',
                  marker = list(size = 5), color=I(co),
                  showlegend=FALSE)

pb <- add_markers(p, 
                  data=b, x=~x, y=~y, name='j', legendgroup='j',
                  marker = list(size = 5), color=I(co),
                  showlegend=TRUE)

pc <- add_histogram(p, x=~xu, name='k', color=I('black'),
                    legendgroup='k', showlegend=FALSE)
pd <- add_histogram(p, x=~xn, name='k', color=I('black'),
                    legendgroup='k', showlegend=TRUE)

plotly::subplot(pa, pb, pc, pd, shareX=TRUE, shareY=FALSE, titleX=TRUE, nrows=4)
```

Note that `mode = 'markers'` (note the plural) is not required if you're using `add_markers`. It is, however, required if you use the more general `add_trace`.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks so much for figuring that out, and for the pointers about markers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will have an answer with `plot_ly()`, but here is an alternative with `ggplot2()` and `ggplotly()`.

You could try this:

```
c <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), y=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c = c("PA", "PA", "PA", "PB", "PB", "PB"), z = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

ggplotly(ggplot(data = c, aes(x = x, y =y)) + 
           geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(z))) + 
           facet_wrap(~ c, ncol = 1) + theme_bw() +  
           theme(
             strip.background = element_blank(),
             strip.text.x = element_blank()
           ) + 
           scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  For this I need to use 'vanilla' `plotly`.